# Getting a Google Doc as text/html

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to import files created in Google Drive (specifically their document format)

I understand that if my app can be used to open MIME type `text/html` as specified in the supported MIME types then I can use the "Open with.." functionality from within Drive to launch my app.

However when I attempt to retrieve the contents via fileId I run into a problem, fileID's only seem to exist for files that are "real" filetypes e.g. I can open a .html file stored in Drive by the id passed to my app.

When trying to open a Google Document I'm passed an exportId - presumably the id of the file that Drive has exported the document to.

I can't find any documentation on how to retrieve a file from its exportID.

The passed 'state' parameter contains the following JSON encoded array.

```
" string(111) "{"exportIds":["14JZ-Lf5BpU0h8bNufrmiWgz1bd184BfyPvdgmiwBDyU"],"action":"open","userId":"110065623489887237624"}"
```

I can only assume that exportIds is an array as the document could be exported to multiple formats, each format having a uniquire exportId.

Update:

So I was pretty much there with my assumptions, but I've found this which suggests I should have access to `exportLinks`

> Once it has the export IDs, an app can fetch the file metadata and extract the desired download URL from the exportLinks values. These are key-value pairs in which the key is a MIME type and the value is the download URL for the converted file. The app can download the converted file content from the download URL. Apps can display converted files as read-only, or let users save them as new files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your assumption isn't quite right.

exportIds are identical to ids. Drive sends the ids as exportIds simply to give you a hint that the ids refer to Google docs rather than simple files. So use the exportId to grab the File object and you're good to go. The reason it's an array is because the user may have selected multiple files to be opened, so you need to iterate the array and process each one.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't think my app in the Drive API settings supports opening multiple files but I'll iterate over them just to be certain.